# Ember.js - Error States in Pod structure

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

Here is my structure in inside `àpp/pods`:

```
|-application
|-index
|-error
|-user
||-index
||-view
||-edit
```

When a error occurs, ember does not load the `error` route.
Instead it tries to load a sub-route like `index_error` or `user_error` but these do not exist.

How do i force Ember to load the root `error` route on any error?

Ember v2.1
Ember-Cli v1.13.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure you've provided should actually do exactly what you're describing you're after.

Take a look at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/de374b3a2e4af9088603) to see an example. Clicking 'View User' will transition to the `user.view` route, but clicking 'Edit User' will raise an exception in the `user.edit` route and instead land you on the `error` route.

One thing to note is that you **should not** add the error route yourself in `router.js`. It receives the transition error as its model, so if you manually do `this.route('error')` and don't give it a dynamic segment, the transition will fail.

---

If you want more control over exactly what happens when an error occurs during *any* transition, you can implement the `error` action on your application route.

```
actions: {
  error(thrownError) {
    this.transitionTo('my-error-route'); // Or whatever other handling you want
  }
}
```

You can see a full example of such an arrangement in [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/d8fdd21473fd93019f82). Note that this is subtly different from the [default error behavior](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/#toc_code-error-code-substates) in that it will produce a full transition (i.e. the URL will be updated) rather than just moving into a substate.

Comment: Well, your answer did not solve the problem in my application, but you proved that is should. +50

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to show an error route inside a pod structure like the following:

```
-app
--pods
----something
------template.hbs
------route.js
----error
------template.hbs
```

If I throw an error on something/route.js like the following:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model() {
   throw new Error('AAA');
 }

});
```

And have the `error/template.hbs` with the content:

```
Arrrh, errror!!!!
```

It displays the error message.

If you wanted a error sub route for `something` I think you would need the following:

```
-app
--pods
----something
------template.hbs
------route.js
------error
--------template.hbs
----error
------template.hbs
```

Comment: could you provide a twiddle of the error of the subroute `something`? I cannot get it working.

Answer (score 0):

http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/

According to the above `app/application/error` is the default in a pod structure.